# How can I substract in prolog the elements from this structure: s(1, [[],[],[],[]] )? I need the integer and the matrix

Tags: prolog

I am quite new in prolog and I've met this structure and I could not figure out how to substact the integer (1) and the matrix.
The exact structure is:

```
s(1,
    [
        [[a], [b, c], [f], [s]],
        [[4], [k],    [1], [5]],
        [[f], [s],    [w], []],
        [[4], [],     [w], [3, 53]]
    ]
)
```

I've tried with functions that extract elements of lists/matrices, but I haven't met anything in () before.

Comment: Don't think of it as a list of list of list but as a list of list of terms, then just remove `[1]`  as term in a list.

Comment: You've called it "substract" and "substact" - do you mean "subtract"? Also, what does it mean to "subtract" (if that's the correct word) a `1` from the matrix?

Comment: I have a structure that looks like this: `s(Integer, [[[]]]) ` ----->it is an s, then in the () parentheses, it contains an integer, then separated by a comma a list of lists of lists (the members of the lists can be integers or characters also and any number of them). Now I need to find out the value of the integer and do something with that, then the same with the list. I've written some functions on how to return values from lists in square brackets, but I cannot do the same with the parentheses.

Comment: You can destructure it just like a list: `s(Integer, Matrix) = s(1, [])` will result in `Integer` being bound to `1` and `Matrix` to `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a variable with the content `s(Integer, Matrix)` and want to extract the `Integer` and `Matrix`. This is actually quite easy:

Lets go with a dummy object `S = s(3, [[[1,2],[a,b]]])`. You only have `S` and want to access `3` and `[[[1,2],[a,b]]]`

```
?- S = s(3, [[[1,2],[a,b]]]), 
   S = s(I,M).

I = 3,
M = [[[1, 2], [a, b]]],
S = s(3, [[[1, 2], [a, b]]])
```

You can put this in some kind of function too. The following example will output an addtion if the predicate name is `a`, a substraction for `s` and or `h` it will put the first parameter as head of a list of the second parameter:

```
doIt(a(A,B),Out) :-
    Out is A+B.
doIt(s(A,B),Out) :-
    Out is A-B.
doIt(h(A,B),[A|B]).

?- doIt(a(2,1),A).
A = 3

?- doIt(s(2,1),A).
A = 1

?- doIt(h(2,1),A).
A = [2|1]
```

Comment: yes thank you! I could solve it easily, I just did not know Prolog is so flexible and overcomplicated it